# fixest::iplot(), dropping some factors

Tags: r, coefplot

I am using `fixest` (version 0.9.0), and I want to omit a numerical factor in the plot of the fixed effects generated by `iplot()`.

```
library(fixest)
reg1 <- feols(mpg ~ disp + i(carb, ref = 8), data = mtcars)
fdict <-  c("2" = "two", "3" = "three")
etable(reg1, dict = fdict)
```

The summary replaces values 2 and 3 with the defined labels. However, no category is  dropped when I try to run any of the following

```
iplot(reg1, dict = fdict, drop = "two")
iplot(reg1, dict = fdict, drop = "two|three")
iplot(reg1, dict = fdict, drop = "%2")
```

How do I omit the desired category/ies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, the developer is working on this issue: https://github.com/lrberge/fixest/issues/164.

UPD (Sept 21): the bug is resolved!